# Where to set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable?

Tags: environment-variables, google-authentication, google-api-python-client

I am trying to use Python to call a Google Cloud AI platform training API. The path to my service account key JSON file is "/Users/my_mac_username/service_account_key.json", and I added the export statement in the bash_profile file so that it looks like:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.8
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/my_mac_username/service_account_key.json"
```

However, I still got the error:

```
google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials.
```

Besides, I have google-cloud-sdk folder installed. I would like to know in which file I should set the environment variable. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you run `echo $GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` from the command line you get back the correct data? Have you opened a new console since setting the value in your bash_profile?

Comment: No I got an empty string

Comment: Run `source ~/.bash_profile` to load your profile or open an new terminal window. You can also run, `export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/my_mac_username/service_account_key.json"` directly from that console

Comment: Thanks man it fixes the issue! Is there a way to permanently set the environment variable?

Comment: Your setting in ~/.bash_profile will do that assuming you are running a bash terminal. You can see by running `echo $SHELL` in your terminal

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your terminal shell is `bash`, you have your environment variable setup correctly. The new variable will not be available until you reopen the terminal or run `source ~/.bash_profile` in the current terminal.

If you are running zsh, add the export in your `~/.zshrc` file.

To determine which shell you're currently running, use: `echo $SHELL` from the command line